# JSON WEATHER API error

Tags: android, json, permissions

i have created a weather app using open weather api and its crashing when i click the button to determine weather.. following is logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                                                                           at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                                                                           at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
                                                                           at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
                                                                           at com.example.hemantj.weather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:133)
                                                                           at com.example.hemantj.weather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:92)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Below is the code ... i have used ANDROID TARGET SDK 25 and MIN SDK as 23.. so marshmallow is involved .. so if anything related to permissions is wrong also point it out...

```
weather.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                try {

                    //to hide the keyboard after pressing the button
                    InputMethodManager manager =
                            (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    manager.hideSoftInputFromInputMethod(weatherInput.getWindowToken(),0);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    //used to encode the entered input for url.. for example San Fransisco appears in url
                    //as San%20Fransisco ... and to enable that we use the encoder...
                    String encodedCity = URLEncoder.encode(city,"UTF-8");

                    downloadTask.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCity + "&APPID=0a7808bb8061814df9b6d5fc88d58b8f");

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            else{
                if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.INTERNET)){

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Internet permissions are necessary",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},INTERNET_CODE);
            }
        }
    });
}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while(data != -1){
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;

                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;

        }
        //combined the exceptions MalformedURL and IOException to a common to display a toast msg
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {

            String message = "";

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

            Log.i("Weather content", weatherInfo);

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                String main = "";
                String description = "";

                main = jsonPart.getString("main");
                description = jsonPart.getString("description");

                if (main != "" && description != "") {

                    message += main + ": " + description + "\r\n";

                }

            }

            if (message != "") {

                weatherReport.setText(message);

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your [API key](http://openweathermap.org/appid), so an error is returned and `String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");` is null. So when you try to get `.length` of the array, it's null. Make another String object like below:

`String apiKey = "Put API key here"`;

Then change:

**This**

```
 downloadTask.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCity);
```

**To This**

`downloadTask.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCity + "&appid=" + apiKey);`

Also, make sure you have internet permissions in your Manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: where to put api key ?

Comment: downloadTask.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCity + "&APPID=0a7808bb8061814df9b6d5fc88d58b8f"); I tried this but its still showing the same error.. i think it has got to do something with permissions.. Pls answer it.. as i am stuck with this problem for more than 12 hours , :(

Comment: You don't need to check if `Manifest.permission.INTERNET` is granted, it is considered a [normal](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html) permission. You just need to make sure you add it to your `Manifest.xml`. I'd remove your code that checks if it's granted.

Comment: But its Android M right .. doesnt it require run time permissions?

Comment: It's in the first 2 paragraphs of the link I provided. But to answer your question, run time permissions are only required for `Dangerous Permissions`. Accessing the internet is considered a `Normal Permission`. According to Google, "The system does not prompt the user to grant normal permissions, and users cannot revoke these permissions." This means you do not need to check if it was granted, you only need to include it in your `Manifest.xml`.

Comment: But it shouldnt make a difference right ...? like i am getting the same error even after placing the API key in the link.. why is that so?

Comment: help bro.. ^^^^

Comment: getting same error after running it... `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.hemantj.weather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:120)
                                                                                 at com.example.hemantj.weather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:79`

Comment: help bro...i am getting the same error even after adding API Key and removing permissions at run time...